# How to override mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have this schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    email: {type: String},
    created: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
    deleted: {type: Date,default: undefined}
});
```

And that I add a few rows:

```
const user1 = new User({name: 'bob',email: 'bob@google.com'}); 
const user2 = new User({name: 'mary',email: 'mary@google.com'}); 
const user3 = new User({name: 'alice',email: 'alice@google.com'});
```

When calling

```
User.find({});
```

I will get all three users above.

However, I want add a function to delete them in a soft way. That's why I have the field "deleted".
By doing this:

```
const user = User.find({email: 'bob@google.com'});
user.deleted = Date.now();
```

In mongo, the user bob will have the field deleted NOT undefined.

If I now call again this:

```
    User.find({});
```

Bob will also be delivered. Of course I can add the flag directly like this:

```
User.find({deleted: undefined});
```

But if all database wants to apply this principle, I guess it would be better to centrilize this functionality.

Is this about overriding the mongoose schema? Could somebody point me into the right direction here?

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, you could possibly use a [query middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware).

Comment: use `null` instead of `undefined` on `deleted` filed

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a find with no filters then it will return ALL records. If you don't want some users (such as those who have a date in the 'deleted' field) then you need to put in a filter.

find({}) is equivalent to select * from table. It returns ALL records without any filter.

Comment: Im aware of this. I also wrote in the question. Of course I can filter it directly, but I was looking for something to do it globally.